# Running basename on remote server with xargs does not produce expected results

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh, xargs

Say I have a file `myFile.txt` in a local directory called `~/local/directory`, then the following command produces results as expected (full file path followed by the name of the file only):

```
find ~/local/directory -type f -iname '*myFile*' | xargs -I{} sh -c '{ echo {}; echo $(basename {}); }'
```

However, now let's say I have a file `myFile2.txt` in a directory `~/test/directory` on a remote system called `remote-host`. Trying to run the same command above remotely prints out the full file path both times as if `basename` were not working. What am I doing wrong?

```
ssh -q remote-host "find ~/test/directory -type f -iname '*myFile*' | xargs -I{} sh -c '{ echo {}; echo $(basename {}); }'"
```

(My ultimate goal is to run rsync on files returned by `find` in a remote environment and saving them back locally to a specific directory but a prefix added to the filename, thus the need for basename. This seems more doable using xargs instead of rsync's `-exec` option.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the `$` so that it will be sent literally to the remote machine. Otherwise, `$(basename {})` is executed locally, and the output `{}` is substituted into the `ssh` argument.

```
ssh -q remote-host "find ~/test/directory -type f -iname '*myFile*' | xargs -I{} sh -c '{ echo {}; echo \$(basename {}); }'"
```

Comment: Or use single quotes outside and double inside.

Comment: @LMC That won't work well because they need single quotes around the `sh -c` argument, and you can't nest single quotes.

Comment: @Barmar This works thanks! If you don't mind, what about for the case of multi-hop SSH? `ssh -q proxy-host "ssh -q remote-host \"find ~/test/directory -type f -iname '*myFile*' | xargs -I{} sh -c '{ echo {}; echo \$(basename {}); }'\""` Seems to cause issues as well

Comment: Nesting command lines is always problematic. I recommend you make use of the `proxyHost` setting in `.ssh/config` rather than doing it explicitly in the SSH command line.